# Strange thing happening with Java applet try/catch statement

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Something strange and mysterious is going on with my applet! It involves a person guessing a number, which is then compared with a random number. You keep guessing until you get it right. If you entered something like

```
ewjkgmvf
```

you would get a `NumberFormatException` on the entry field. To solve this problem, I surrounded the turning of the String into the int with try...catch. If the exception was caught, the Label was supposed to display "That is not a number!". Instead, it just said "Too low. Try again" , which was only supposed to happen if your guessed number was too low. What am I doing wrong?

I will post the whole program as it is only a short one.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.Random;
public class Number_guess_applet extends Applet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Button btnClick;
    TextField entry;
    Label prompt;
    String temp;
    Random r = new Random();
    int x = r.nextInt(100);
    int number;
    int keepGoing = 1;

        public void init(){
        prompt = new Label("Guess the number");
        add(prompt);
        entry = new TextField(10);
        add(entry);
        btnClick = new Button("Check your guess");
        add(btnClick);
    }
    public boolean action(Event evt, Object arg){


        temp = entry.getText();
        try
        {
        number = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        }
        catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException e)
        {
        prompt.setText("That is not a number!");
        }
        if (x < number)
            prompt.setText("Too high. Try again.");
        else if (x > number)
            prompt.setText("Too low. Try again.");
        else if (x == number)
            prompt.setText("Found it!");
        else
            prompt.setText("Invalid or not a number. Choose a number between 1 and 100");
        return(true);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the logic into the try / catch - you're executing it afterwards so it's overwriting the prompt text:

```
 try {
        number = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        if (x < number)
            prompt.setText("Too high. Try again.");
        else if (x > number)
            prompt.setText("Too low. Try again.");
        else if (x == number)
            prompt.setText("Found it!");
        else
            prompt.setText("Invalid or not a number. Choose a number between 1 and 100");
 } catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
        prompt.setText("That is not a number!");
 }
 return(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look closely:

```
try
{
    number = Integer.parseInt(temp);
}
catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException e)
{
    prompt.setText("That is not a number!");
}
if (x < number) {
    //...
```

If `NumberFormatException` is thrown you do not set any value to `number`, effectively using the previous one. You should set some value to `number` or skip the logic on `number` altogether. Otherwise your `if (x < number)` condition runs on previous value of `number`.

Comment: so how do I restart the applet? Is there a built in method?

Answer (score 1):

After the catch block finishes executing, the rest of the method executes (with `number` unchanged).

You need to return from the `catch` block.

Comment: And number is probably 0 if the invalid number is the first one entered, which it seems to be in your test. That's why it's too small, not too big.

Answer (score 1):

What it happens is that the prompt got the text "That is not a number!" and immediately  gets the text "Too high. Try again." or "Too low. Try again." or "Found it!" depending on the old value of number, number never gets re-assigned. You can try the following in your action method:

```
        temp = entry.getText();
        try
        {
          number = Integer.parseInt(temp);
          if (x < number)
              prompt.setText("Too high. Try again.");
          else if (x > number)
              prompt.setText("Too low. Try again.");
          else if (x == number)
              prompt.setText("Found it!");
          else
              prompt.setText("Invalid or not a number. Choose a number between 1 and 100");
        }
        catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException e)
        {
        prompt.setText("That is not a number!");
        }

        return(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Number defaults to 0.  Since you are still comparing number to x, you are getting that message.  One option would be to put a return statement inside your catch block.